# How to use radio buttons in gtkmm3?

Tags: gtkmm, gtkmm3

The documentation of GTK+ and gtkmm is bad in my opinion. All it says are things like "this function is deprecated".

Also, I can't find examples that show the exact way of how to use things the new way.

Can someone please show me a fully not-deprecated example using gtkmm3 code that features a popup menu with two different sets of radio buttons and a function that calls `set_active(true)` on one of the buttons?

Here is what I have so far:

```
m_refActionGroup = Gio::SimpleActionGroup::create();
insert_action_group("PlacepieceMenu", m_refActionGroup);
// These are part of one set of radio buttons:
m_refActionGroup->add_action("PlacepieceWhitePawn", sigc::mem_fun(*this, &ChessPositionWidget::on_menu_placepiece_white_pawn));
m_refActionGroup->add_action("PlacepieceBlackRook", sigc::mem_fun(*this, &ChessPositionWidget::on_menu_placepiece_black_rook));
// These should be part of another set of radio buttons in the same menu:
m_refActionGroup->add_action("ToMoveWhite", sigc::mem_fun(*this, &ChessPositionWidget::on_menu_to_move_white));
m_refActionGroup->add_action("ToMoveBlack", sigc::mem_fun(*this, &ChessPositionWidget::on_menu_to_move_black));

m_refBuilder = Gtk::Builder::create();
m_refBuilder->add_from_file("/home/carlo/projects/cwchessboard/PlacePiece.glade");
```

As far as I can tell, the glade file doesn't say which menu item belongs to which radio button group. In fact, it doesn't say anything about what the menu items are at all; here is a piece of the glade file:

```
    <child>
      <object class="GtkMenuItem" id="PlacePieceWhitePawn">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="action_name">PlacepieceMenu.PlacepieceWhitePawn</property>
        <property name="label" translatable="yes">White pawn</property>
        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
      </object>
    </child>
```

Also, no matter what I try, I can't call `set_active` on any of the items.

Comment: If could could post a minimal and reproductible example, it would greatly help.

Comment: @BobMorane I prepared one for the mailinglist, see https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtkmm-list/2020-December/msg00002.html . I did get an answer, but Kjell changed back the ui_info string from how glade outputs it to something else (old style glade? I don't know). I can't use that since I want to use glade and m_refBuilder->add_from_file